# Finite complexes which are not Thom spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'll be working in the stable world. It's an easy observation that any 2-cell complex (over the sphere) with bottom cell in dimension zero is a Thom spectrum: any such complex is the cofiber of some element $\alpha\in \pi_n S$, so it is the Thom spectrum of the map $S^{n+1} \to B\mathrm{GL}_1 S$ classifying $\alpha$. Is there an example of a finite complex (again, with bottom cell in dimension zero, which is a necessary condition) which is *not* a Thom spectrum? Is there such a 3-cell complex?

Edit: I think the question mark complex $Q$ gives an example of such a 3-cell complex. This is the complex constructed by lifting the stable map $\Sigma \eta:S^2\to S^1$ to $\Sigma^{−1}\mathbf{R}P^2$ by choosing a nullhomotopy of $2\eta$; it follows that if $Q$ was to be a Thom spectrum, it would be a Thom spectrum of bundle over a space with bottom cell in dimension 1 and top cell in dimension 3, along with a $\mathrm{Sq}^2$ in cohomology. But $\mathrm{Sq}^2$ (unstably) vanishes on any cohomology class in dimension 1, so this is impossible.

I guess, then, my question could be revised to asking whether there are nontrivial sufficient conditions under which a finite complex can be realized as a Thom spectrum.

Comment: The question mark complex might be an example, but I am not quite convinced with the argument. Just a fun-fact worth mentioning here: the upside down question mark complex i.e. Spanier-Whitehead dual of the question mark complex (up to a shift) is a Thom spectrum. This can be found in a paper of Mahowald ``Ring spectra which are Thom complexes."

 Also I think generalized Moore spectra, such as M(1,4), may not be a Thom spectrum. But cannot think of a quick argument!

Comment: @Prasit I agree that my argument isn't very convincing, and is missing details, but I thought I'd add it in the body of the question anyway in case someone could provide a complete argument. Which section of Mahowald's paper is it in? Here's my idea for proving the statement about the dual question mark complex $DQ$. Identify $SO(3)$ with $\mathbf{R}P^3$, so there is a map $\mathbf{R}P^2 \to SO(3) \to O = \Omega BO$, and hence a map $\Sigma \mathbf{R}P^2 \to BO$. This map detects the nontrivial element of $\pi_2(BO)$ on the bottom cell, so it should Thomify to $DQ$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I agree with your argument. Mahowald in the paper mentioned above, realizes HZ as a Thom spectrum over the Whitehead cover of $\Omega^2S^3$. Not only that he realizes integral Brown-Gitler spectra as Thom spectra over certain subcomplex of $\Omega^2S^3$ obtained from certain `operadic May filtration', viewing  $\Omega^2S^3$ as universal $E_2$ space obtained from $S^1$. The upside down question mark is the first integral Brown-Gitler spectrum. I think this discussion is in section 2, see prop 2.10. But it is essentially the argument you gave above!

Comment: Presumably you've implicitly localized at a prime, otherwise you can't get the mod p Moore complex the way you describe when p>2 since 1-p is not a unit in $\pi_0S^0$.

Comment: actually even that doesn't solve the problem... yeah- if you localize at p, then the mod p+1 Moore complex seems problematic, right?

Comment: @DylanWilson I do not quite get your question. what do you mean when you say mod p+1 Moore complex localized at prime p. Isn't it trivial anyway? (Since p+1 is a unit in p-adics).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I should really be working at some fixed prime p. (I was thinking about p=2 but the evenness of the prime shouldn't matter.)

Comment: @Prasit good point :) and then I suppose that $0$ is a Thom spectrum over the empty set, so that works (or isn't allowed anyway since we restrict to complexes with a bottom $0$-cell).

Comment: Anyway, for the actual question: can you turn Mahowald's proof that $bo$ isn't a Thom spectrum into a proof that some skeleton of it isn't?

Comment: I'm probably being stupid (I don't know anything about this stuff) but if $X$ is a finite complex, then $\Sigma^n X$ is is a suspension spectrum for some $n$, and in particular the Thom spectrum of a trivial bundle. Then can't you just desuspend the bundle $n$ times to exhibit $X$ as a Thom spectrum?

Comment: @TimCampion I assume they want a Thom spectrum of a *rank 0* stable spherical fibration (since they mention of $BGL_1(\mathbb{S})$ and not $BGL_1(\mathbb{S})\times \mathbb{Z}$), so you're not allowed to desuspend.

Comment: Ah, I just reread, and Sanath also says he wants the bottom cell in dimension zero. Still, I'd like to know "the official word" because I don't really know what people mean by default when they say that something "is a Thom spectrum".

Comment: @TimCampion I think it depends on the context. In more recent papers, something seems to be called "a Thom spectrum" if it is a Thom spectrum of a rank zero stable spherical fibration, but in older papers, I would imagine that "Thom spectrum" could mean the more general notion of Thom spectrum (i.e., Z x BGL_1) that you had in mind.

Comment: I feel like the opposite is true: nowadays we like to map to pic(S) instead of BGL_1(S)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I got it the wrong way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proposed argument for why $Q = S \cup_2 e^1 \cup_\eta e^3$ is not a Thom spectrum seems to use that the Thom isomorphism commutes with the Steenrod operations, which is often false.  The deviation is measured by the Stiefel-Whitney classes.

If $Q$ were the Thom spectrum $B^\gamma$ of a stable spherical fibration $\gamma$ over a space $B$, then $H^*(B; Z/2) = Z/2\{1, b_1, b_3\}$ would have trivial $Sq^i$-actions (by instability) and $H^*(Q; Z/2) = Z/2\{U, Ub_1, Ub_3\}$ would be a free (right) module over $H^*(B; Z/2)$ on one generator $U \in H^0(Q; Z/2)$, the $Z/2$-orientation class.  Then $Sq^i(U) = U w_i$, where $w_i$ is the $i$-th Stiefel-Whitney class of $\gamma$.  Since $Sq^1(U) = U b_1$ and $Sq^2(U) = 0$ in the cohomology of $Q$, you must have $w_1 = b_1$ and $w_2 = 0$.  Then $Sq^2(U b_1) = 0$ by the Cartan formula, contradicting $Sq^2(Ub_1) = Ub_3$ in $H^*(Q; Z/2)$.  So $Q$ is not a Thom spectrum.

The paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.08388.pdf by Basu, Sagave and Schlichtkrull gives a sufficient condition for realizing some finite $R$-modules as $R$-Thom spectra, where $R$ is even.  This does not include the classical case $R = S$, but might still be of interest.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.